# syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')' @attempt.name = params[:content][:attempt_name][:value]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add "mercury" gem, but I got error mentioned in the title.

Here is my method:

```
 def mercury_update
  @attempt = Attempt.find(params[:id]
  @attempt.name = params[:content][:attempt_name][:value]
  @attempt.content = params[:content][:attempt_content][:value]
  @attempt.save!
  end
```

and here is my view:

```
 <h1 id="attempt_name" class="mercury-region" data-mercury="full"><%= raw @attempt.name %></h1>
    <%= render 'form' %>
    <p id="attempt_content" class="mercury-region" data-mercury="full" > <%= raw @attempt.content %> </p>
    <p><%= link_to "Edit Page", "/editor" + request.path, id: "edit_link", data: { save_url: mercury_update_attempt_path(@attempt) } %></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the `find` parenthesis

```
@attempt = Attempt.find(params[:id])
```